# Angular RxJS: Hot Observable turned to Cold

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This is my related code:

```
private searchClickSubject:Subject<void>;  // Submit form
private searchClick$:Observable<any>;
private metrics$:Observable<MetricGroup>;

constructor() {
    // Prepare observers
    this.searchClickSubject = new Subject<void>();
    this.searchClick$ = this.searchClickSubject.asObservable();
}

public ngOnInit() {
    // Grab search button click event
    this.searchQuery$ = this.searchClick$.pipe(
        map(() => <Query>{
            offset: 0,
            limit: AmetriquesComponent.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
        })
    );

    const loading = () => tap(() => this.loadingPage());
    const getAggregatedMetrics = () => switchMap((query: Query) => this.service.getAggregatedMetrics(query));
    const loaded = () => tap((aggregatedMetrics: MetricGroup) => this.loadedMetric(aggregatedMetrics));

    this.metrics$ = this.searchQuery$
        .pipe(
            loading(),
            getAggregatedMetrics(),
            loaded(),
            share()
        );
}
```

First of all, I think `searchClick$` Observable is hot, since form is generating on submit events regardless of any subscription is attached on.

As you can see, after an "submit" event is emitted, I make an http request. So for each "submit form" emitted a new http request is emitted.

When I attach a subscription on that last Observable, a separate http request is made, so it sounds like first Observable has turned on a cold Observable.

What do you think about my train of thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

I still see this as a hot observable since it will never emit a complete notification. The inner subscription of `getAggregatedMetrics` will emit one, but not the outer one. Also `share()` turns cold observables hot per [this article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339). Unless I'm not understanding the question?